# Chrome native PDF reader open hyperlinks in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I tried to include a PDF in a iframe, passing the file URL in the DOM element src field. When I clicked on a hyperlink in the document, the target is opened in a new tab instead of replacing the iframe content, as I expected.

I have to mention, I already tried PDF.js and viewer.js but they do not display hyperlinks, and it is an feature I have been asked for. I also tried manipulating the iframe content with jQuery (**file was, at this moment, on the same domain**) :

- Adding a *base* element (added, but no effects),
- Adding a *onbeforeunload* event (no effect).

If only I could get access to the hyperlinks target...

I hope you can help me !

Comment: Are pdf file is same domain?

Comment: Yes, when I tried to manipulate content with jQuery.

Comment: See PDFJS.externalLinkTarget https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L221

Answer (score 0):

This is native functionality of the browser and you're not going to be able to fix that. I expect you're only option will be to add link support to PDF.js yourself.

Don't bother with viewer.js for this, as it's just a wrapper for PDF.js.